# Once content has completely loaded via ajax, how to run more script after fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm loading content via ajax, but I am trying to fire the `specSlide();` after my appended data has fully loaded or completed...

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/bike-profile.php',
    data:
        {
            varbike : bikes
        },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){

        $(currentSlideHtmlObject).append(data);

        specSlide();

    }

});
```

Comment: What does the specSlide() function do?

Comment: Its running general jquery css/animation on the appened content, but it seems specSlide is running before all the images etc have loaded.

Comment: The function most definetively runs after the ajax has completed, and appending is synchronous, so the content is also appended. However the images will need to load, and to wait for that you'll need some trickery with an image object and an onload function.

Comment: Try using [imagepreload plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) of jquery.Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajaxSuccess](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxSuccess) More here: http://www.slideshare.net/wildan.m/jquery-talk-to-server-with-ajax (after slide 47)